# how to name CouchDB Key Value fields

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I asked this question previously but did not seem to make myself clear.
When emitting values from a CouchDB View like:

```
{emit(doc.payload.creator, doc.payload.startTS);}
```

Is it possible to somehow "name" or "label" the results?  I would like to return the Key as "Created by" and the Value as "Start Time".

Comment: You somehow want to return `{ "Created by":key, "Start time": value}`  or `{"key":"Create by "+key,"value":"Start time " +value}`?

Answer (score 0):

In the view function definition you can use this kind of operations in order to build the value as a JSON document with the required attributes

```
function (doc) {
  var value = {};
  value['Created By'] = doc.payload.creator;
  value['Start Time'] = doc.payload.startTS;
  emit(doc.payload.creator, value);
}
```

If you would like to export the data in a different format you may use a list function over the view results.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#list-functions